# Why React gives: hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have three projects CORE, COMPONENTS and BUILDER.

The CORE project is linked to COMPONENTS project with next line in package.json

```
"core": "file:../path-to-core-project"
```

Then COMPONENTS project in linked to BUILDER project with next line in package.json

```
"components": "file:../path-to-components-project"
```

Now, in CORE project I have:

```
const DataContextProvider = ({ children, configuration }) => {
  return (
    <ClientContext.Provider value={client}>
      <DataContext.Provider value={someValue}>
        {children}
      </DataContext.Provider>
    </ClientContext.Provider>
  );

}
```

The DataContextProvider is exported from CORE projects and it is used in both other projects COMPONENTS project and BUILDER project.

That gives me an error because two instance of React (the one from COMPONENTS and the one from BUILDER) try to use the same hook. This gives me an error: "**hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component**"

All three projects are using React 18.2.0 version.

Any idea?

I also tried to go to COMPONENTS project/node_modules/react and I did `yarn link` there to create link of that React instance and then in BUILDER `yarn link react` to link it, but the same error.

Exact error is as follows:

react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
   at exports.DataContextProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:542265:11)

Comment: Even if they are using the same version, if they are importing different instances (e.g. different `node_modules` for each project), it could lead to that issue.

Comment: That said, it looks like you're using some multi projects setup, which seems to be relevant to the issue, but there's not enough info about your setup to help.